# "IM Büro kommen"?

Tags: grammatical-case

In einem Übungsbuch steht folgender Satz:

> Im Taxi zum Flughafen hat sie einen Anruf von ihrer Kollegin bekommen,
> die sie gebeten hat, noch einmal kurz **im Büro** zu einer Besprechung zu
> kommen.

Könntet Ihr mir bitte erklären, warum hier "IM Büro" steht? Wenn ich vom Verb ausgehend die Frage stelle (*Wohin hat sie sie gebeten zu kommen?*), würde ich den Akkusativ benutzen (also "*ins Büro*"). Steht hier der Dativ, weil die Besprechung IM Büro stattfindet?

Comment: Es ist ein Fehler im Buch. Sie haben Recht, dass es wohl *ins Büro kommen* heißen sollte. Zwar kann man auch *im Büro kommen*, aber das hat eine andere (sexuelle) Bedeutung, wie übrigens auch im Englischen.

Comment: @Björn Friedrich + amadeusamadeus: Vielen lieben Dank für Eure Antworten! Ich hätte die Community viel früher fragen sollen! Habe mir den ganzen Abend den Kopf darüber zerbrochen, wie es „IM Büro kommen“ sein kann =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es handelt sich vermutlich um einen Fehler. Im gegebenen Beispiel ist tatsächlich nur korrekt:

> […], die sie gebeten hat, noch einmal kurz **ins** Büro zu einer Besprechung zu kommen.

Eine Spekulation wäre, dass der Satz ursprünglich anders lautete:

> […], die sie gebeten hat, noch einmal kurz **zu einer Besprechung im Büro** zu kommen.

Selbst dann könnte man jedoch höchstens antworten:

> Wohin hat sie sie gebeten zu kommen?
>
> – Zu einer Besprechung im Büro.

nicht aber

> – <s>Im Büro zu einer Besprechung</s>.

Wie @BjörnFriedrich anmerkt, hätte das eine ungewollte Bedeutungsverschiebung zur Folge.

Comment: Die Umordnung "im Büro noch einmal kurz zu einer Besprechung zu kommen" wäre auch möglich und hätte wieder eine leicht andere Bedeutung, die allerdings nicht gut zum hier implizierten Kontext passen würde. Der Satz deutet ja an, dass sie eigentlich dabei ist, sich für längere Zeit zu entfernen, während durch "noch einmal kurz" angedeutet wird, dass die Besprechung dieses Entfernen kurzzeitig unterbricht. "Im Büro noch einmal kurz zu einer Besprechung" enthielte hingegen die Bedeutung, dass sie ohnehin noch im Büro vorbeikommt und bei der Gelegenheit der Besprechung beiwohnen soll.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Das wäre dann der Fall, wenn "das Büro" nicht einen einzelnen Büroraum meint, sondern mehrere zusammen genutzte Räume, bespielsweise die Büroräume einer Firma oder einer Filiale, richtig? Also wenn "Ich gehe ins Büro" nicht zwingend meint, dass man in einen bestimmten Raum geht, sondern praktisch äquivalent ist zu "Ich gehe in die Firma". Ich stimme allerdings zu, dass es sich wahrscheinlich um einen Fehler handelt.

Comment: @amadeusamadesu Man könnte "im Büro" auch als nähere Beschreibung von "Besprechung" lesen. Der Unterschied wäre dann "Wohin soll sie kommen? Ins Büro, wegen einer Besprechung" im Gegensatz zu "Wohin soll sie kommen? Zu der Besprechung, die _im Büro_ stattfindet."

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck: Richtig, zumindest hier in Südwestdeutschland wird "das Büro" als Synonym für "die Firma" bzw. "das Firmengebäude" genutzt, wenn man dort tatsächlich in Büroräumen arbeitet. Von dieser Verwendung ist auch beim Originalsatz auszugehen, schon allein aus dem Grund, dass größere "Besprechungen im Büro" (Firmengebäude) eben üblicherweise gerade nicht in einem Büro (Raum) stattfinden, sondern in einem Besprechungsraum.

Answer (score 1):

> Im Taxi zum Flughafen hat sie einen Anruf von ihrer Kollegin bekommen, die sie gebeten hat, noch einmal kurz im Büro zu einer Besprechung *vorbei* zu kommen.

Richtigerweise wird vorbeizukommen zusammengeschrieben, aber man sieht immer wieder den Fehler, dass Leute es so auseinander schreiben. Vergisst man in so einer falschen Konstruktion auch noch versehentlich das Wort *vorbei*, entsteht ebenfalls der angefragte Satz.

Comment: Ich finde die Erklärung, wie der Fehler zustandegekommen sein könnte, plausibel.

Answer (score 0):

> ... im Büro zu einer Besprechung zu kommen.

Diesen Satzteil verstehe ich als:

> ... zu einer Besprechung zu kommen.

... wobei zum Satzteil noch eine zusätzliche Ortsangabe hinzufügt ist - wie in diesem Beispiel:

> Ich nehme den Papierstapel.
>
> Im Büro nehme ich den Papierstapel.

Demnach bedeutet "*i**ns** Büro zu einer Besprechung kommen*", dass man sich außerhalb des Büros aufhält und in das Büro kommt, um an der Besprechung teilzunehmen.

"*I**m** Büro zu einer Besprechung kommen*" bedeutet hingegen, dass man sich bereits innerhalb des Büros befindet und nun zur Besprechung kommt.

Man könnte um 13:00 Uhr "*ins*" Büro zur Besprechung kommen, sich dann eine Stunde in anderen Räumen des Büros aufhalten und dann um 14:00 Uhr "*im*" Büro zur Besprechung kommen.

Würde man sich mit dem Anrufer, der den Anruf getätigt hat, über die korrekte Grammatik streiten, könnte der sich darauf berufen, dass er die Angerufene darum gebeten hat, um 14:00 Uhr "*im*" Büro zur Besprechung zu kommen, was natürlich voraussetzt, dass sie zu einem früheren Zeitpunkt "*ins*" Büro zur Besprechung kommt.